# Which topic studies the symmetry/antisymmetry of products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Suppose we have a ring $R$ and $u, v, w, a_0, ..., a_n$ are elements of the ring

I have encountered some work which takes the following concepts for granted:

1) formation of symmetric/antisymmetric expressions like $uv + vu$ (symmetric) or $uv - vu$ (antisymmetric)

2) more generally, the formation of "antisymmetrized" expressions: 
$$ \frac{1}{r!}\sum_{\sigma} \textrm{sgn}(\sigma) a_{\sigma(1)}a_{\sigma(2)}\dots a_{\sigma_{(n)}} $$

...and I guess "symmetrized" expressions would be:

$$ \frac{1}{r!}\sum_{\sigma} a_{\sigma(1)}a_{\sigma(2)}\dots a_{\sigma_{(n)}} $$

(haven't seen an example of that mentioned yet)

3) properties with of products with even/odd number of factors

I am not too used to paying attention to these aspects of an algebra. Are there some keywords I can use to help find references on such things?

**Edit:** A bit of searching on my part has revealed that this has something to do with "graded algebras" (the stuff I am studying does have a graded structure).

Comment: You need to have a Q structure, otherwise how do you know that you can divide by r!

Comment: I don’t know much about it, but if you’re not already familiar, you might want to have a look at symmetric and exterior powers. They are strongly reminiscent of the summation expressions you’ve given.

Comment: Those are isotypical projectors for the trivial and sign representations of $S_n$, but I've not seen it applied to ring elements (instead of just module elements using tensors) like that.